# How to generate query in mongodb which handles null filters?

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

I know that the question is not clear enough.
I will try to explain it here with the help of an example.

I have the following data in **RDBMS**

***`ITEM            MATERIAL`***
    `pen             plastic`
    `cell phone      plastic`
    `mirror          glass`
    `tshirt          cloth`
    `bedsheet        cloth`

In my code, I have a variable `material` and the following query
`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE MATERIAL = {material} OR {material} = NULL;`

Consider the following scenarios,

If `material == "plastic"`, then the output will be

***`ITEM            MATERIAL`***
    `pen             plastic`
    `cell phone      plastic`

If `material == "glass"`, then the output will be

***`ITEM            MATERIAL`***
    `mirror          glass`

But, if `material ==`**`null`**, then the output will be (no filter applied)

***`ITEM            MATERIAL`***
    `pen             plastic`
    `cell phone      plastic`
    `mirror          glass`
    `tshirt          cloth`
    `bedsheet        cloth`

I want to implement the same in **mongodb**.
A single query which will filter the data based on the value of `material`, but applies no filter when `material == null`.

How to achieve this?

How should I modify the query object `{"material" : _the_variable_material_}` to achieve the same result?

Or is there any other approach to handle this?

Following is the **mongodb** document containing same data.

```
{
    "item": "pen",
    "material": "plastic"
},
{
    "item": "cell phone",
    "material": "plastic"
},
{
    "item": "mirror",
    "material": "glass"
},
{
    "item": "tshirt",
    "material": "cloth"
},
{
    "item": "bedsheet",
    "material": "cloth"
}
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE MATERIAL = {material} OR {material} IS NULL;`

Comment: @lad2025, I will keep that in mind. My actual problem is to achieve the similar result in **mongodb**

Comment: Are you using any language driver?

Comment: @SSDMS Yes, I am using Spring Data Mongo in Java

Comment: I am not  familiar with Spring but I think I simple if statement will be enough.

Comment: @SSDMS The if-else would work when the filter is applied on few attributes. It is not feasible to write nested if-else ladder if the filter is applied on 7-8 attributes. That's why I want to implement this using a single query object, like it can be done using SQL.

Comment: I can extend the SQL like `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (MATERIAL = {material} OR {material} = NULL) AND (STORE = {store} OR {store} = NULL) AND (CITY = {city} OR {city} = NULL) AND (INSTOCK = {instock} OR {instock} = NULL)`. This query will not apply filter on the columns where the variable is `null`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to perform this query is to nest it in an if statement that evaluates the value of _the_variable_material_:

```
if(_the_variable_material_ === 'null'){
    db.collection.find({});
} else {
    db.collection.find({ $or: [ { "material": _the_variable_material_ }, {"material": {$exists: false}}, {"material": null} ] })
}
```

or, in a single query but lower performance:

```
    db.collection.find({ $or: [ { "material": _the_variable_material_ }, {"material": {$exists: false}}, {"material": null}, {$where: "this._the_variable_material_ == 'null'" } ] })
```

Comment: The attribute `material` is not set to `null` in any document. I want the filter to not work when the variable `{material}` is `null` like it is happening in case of SQL, `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE MATERIAL = {material} OR {material} = NULL;`
When the variable `{material}` is null, all the records will be returned irrespective of the value of the column `material`

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you only want to return all records, if at least one record is null, otherwise you want to return none, is that right?

Comment: No, I want to ignore the filter if the variable `material` is `null`. Ex., if `material == 'plastic'`, I want the query to work like `db.collection.find({"material": null})`. And if `material == null`, I want the query to work like `db.collection.find()`.   How to achieve this using the same query object?

Comment: Yes, it works when the document has the attribute `material` with value `null`. Not when the variable `material` is `null`.

Comment: Now I think I understand. I will update my answer as soon as I can sit down.

Comment: Though your approach works fine, but it does not solve my problem. I am interested in using a single query instead of 2 as in your answer. When more attributes need to be filtered, your approach will require nested if-else statements and 2^n different queries. While, in case of SQL, I can use a single query to achieve the same, `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (MATERIAL = {material} OR {material} = NULL) AND (STORE = {store} OR {store} = NULL) AND (CITY = {city} OR {city} = NULL) AND (INSTOCK = {instock} OR {instock} = NULL)`

Comment: You need to use $where then, but it is sometimes not a very good option for performance reasons.